# SQL new column with pattern match

Tags: sql, t-sql, pattern-matching, design-patterns, substr

I have a column with a url sting that looks like this

http://www.somedomain.edu/rootsite1/something/something/
or 
http://www.somedomain.edu/sites/rootsite2/something/something

Basically I want to ONLY return the string up to root site (in another column).. root site can be anyting (but /sites), but it will either follow /sites/ or .edu/

so the above two strings would return:

```
http://www.somedomain.edu/rootsite1
http://www.somedomain.edu/sites/rootsite2
```

I can't compile the view with CLR, so I don't think Regex is an option.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are typical values for `'rootsite'`? If you are going to use string functions, this is an important point.

Comment: part of url .. can be any string and can contain %20

Comment: So how would you define, *technically*, where to cut the URL?

Comment: @Tomalak: Going on his examples, it appears to be after the first directory past either `/sites/` or `.edu/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll do better by splitting up the URL on the client side and saving it as two pieces in the table (one containing the "root" site, the other containing the site-specific path), then putting them back together again on the client side after retrieval.

If you choose to store them in the table as you describe above, you can use `CHARINDEX` to determine where the `.edu` or `/sites/` occurs in the string, then use `SUBSTRING` to break it up based on that index.

If you really need to do this, here's an example:

```
declare @sites table (URL varchar(500))

insert into @sites
values
('http://www.somedomain.edu/rootsite1/something/something/'),
('http://www.somedomain.edu/sites/rootsite2/something/something')

select
    URL,
    SUBSTRING(URL, 1, case when charindex('/sites/', URL) > 0 then 
        charindex('/', URL, charindex('/sites/', URL) + 7) else 
        charindex('/', URL, charindex('.edu/', URL) + 5) end - 1)

from @sites
```

Comment: yes.. split up the string by "/" into tokens and then condition for sites I guess.. How would I do that in an inline view?

Comment: @cyberpine: Splitting by tokens is not necessary. I still recommend *not* doing this in the database, but if you must then I'll post an example.

Comment: If you have an inline sql select example, I'd like to see it. If I can't do it in the view, I'd have to do in jquery client code and rather not because once I have the column I was hoping to use it for sorting and distinct dataset selecting in the view. Thanks!

Comment: @cyberpine: My point is that *you should not be performing the split in the database*. If your data actually represents a "root" site combined with a relative path inside of it, then store your data that way. When your client inserts a URL, perform that split in client code and insert the two values into two different columns. When your client retrieves the URL, combine the two values into one URL. Doing this sort of string manipulatin in the database will completely eliminate the possibility of indexing. Considering your purpose for this is for sorting and filtering, indexing is called for.

Answer (score 0):

you could use CHARINDEX, LEN and SUBSTRING to do this although im not sure sql is the best place to do it

```
DECLARE @testStr VARCHAR(255)
SET @testStr = 'http://www.somedomain.edu/rootsite1/something/something/'

PRINT SUBSTRING(@testStr, 0, CHARINDEX('.edu', @testStr))
```

Not a full solution but should give you a start